# How can I shorten/fix this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is pretty simple, but I don't know how to do it. If I had a command block constantly running

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:coal_block
```

How would I use the player that the command block just picked up in a teleportation command? Would I some how shorten/fix it like

```
/testfor @a[r=3]
```

then some teleport command instead of just using

```
/tp @a[r=3] (where ever)
```

Okay, so is there some way to put this in one single command or make it so the person the command targets actually gets remembered/tagged I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `detect` scheme of the [`execute` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute), which is a slightly changed testforblock coupled to execute:

```
/execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> detect <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> <data> <command …>
```

This command will only resolve targets which have a `<block>` with the specified `<data>` (-1 matches all) at `<x2> <y2> <z2>` (can be relative coordinates). `<command …>`  will be executed relative to `<x> <y> <z>`, as usual for execute.

To TP everyone standing on a coal block, for example, you can use

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:coal_block -1 tp @a[c=1] <X> <Y> <Z>
```

Of course, you can further limit the target by adding target selector arguments to the target selector of the execute command, such as `@a[r=10]` or `@a[tag=teleport]`.